# How to select a triangle in XNA?

Tags: xna, transparency, textures

I have a triangle with a transparent background (png image) I want its color to change when selecting it.

The point is that the color should change only when touching the non-transparent part of the image.

This should be working when the image is scaled..

Any ideas please?

Thanks...

Comment: Do you have a specific kind of triangle you want to determine the collision (equilateral, isosceles, etc) or randomly generated triangles?

Comment: thanks for reply,,

consider it a png image, not necessary triangle, but the point is that there is a transparent background..

I want the program to make an event when I touch the triangle itself, not the background of the image, since it is transparent..

and what if we re-sized the image? I want the program run the same way when I re-size it.. 

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not know the exact size/shape of the triangle, you'll need to use Per-Pixel collision detection. The App Hub has a [tutorial](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/tutorial/collision_2d_perpixel_transformed) for that. It even works with scaled/rotated objects.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. of course it helps.

But I want to modify the code a little bit, the code of transformed collision; since I have only one Sprite.

I can add a 1x1 pixel image and move it to the position of touch, then apply the code, but that is not practical.

i hope I can find a way to detect collision between a Sprite and a point using the link you mentioned.. Thanks.